# Numerical multi-dimensional integration of a complex function

Tags: c++, integration, gsl, numerical-integration

I have two functions

```
std::complex<double> foo(double x, double y);
double bar(double x, double y);
```

and I am trying to compute the following integral:

```
\int dx \int dy foo(x,y)*bar(x,y) .
```

It would certainly be possible to split this integral into its real and imaginary part and integrate those seperately using the routines provided by GSL, however, the function `bar` is computationally very expensive (and runtime is important), so that I would like to avoid calling `bar` twice. Is there any library that would allow me to perform this integration (or do you hav a suggestion how to perform this integral without having to call bar twice as much)?

I should probably also state that both are member functions of a class.

Comment: With "avoid calling `bar` twice", I assume you mean "avoid calling it twice for the same input". If so, you could wrap `bar` in another function, that stores the result for all given `x, y` combinations and returns the stored valued in case of a repeated evaluation for the same `x, y`.

Comment: What are your limits of integration? If they are constant, I'd probably pick one of the many c2 integration methods of [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/#quadrilateral-c2) and implement it myself.

Comment: Could you give us some information on `bar`? I do MRI simulation and the magnetic field vector in the plane is calculated in complex figures. You might be doing all the mistakes, that we used to do in the beginning. I really believe that GSL is not necessarily the place to go. I like CVODE a lot. It is a variable time stepping solver, which does magic for the runtime. But also it turned out, that when we integrate magnitude and phase, we accelerate another 2000 times the integration. You find what I coauthored https://github.com/jemris/jemris

Comment: please excuse the very late answer, I have not been checking stackoverflow for a while since I had to put that project on hold. If you are interested, the function I am wanting to integrate is Eq. (15) of https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2005/07/aa0217-03.pdf
I transform the (l1,l2)-integral into polar coordinates (r,psi), so that the argument of the bessel functions only depends on r. I then solve the r-integral with the methods of Ogata et al (2005). The result is my (real-valued) bar. The prefactors of the remaining (phi,psi) integration are foo.